# Can't connect my client to the qt server example on OSX

Tags: macos, qt, url, network-programming, localhost

I open the Qt example of webserver. All work fine with it and i can see the following properties :

[image]

When i try to connect the example of client, nothing happen. These lines :

```
  m_webSocket.open(QStringLiteral("http://localhost:1921")));


    qDebug() << "Port :" <<m_webSocket.peerPort();
    qDebug() << "Name :" <<m_webSocket.peerName();
    qDebug() << "Port :" <<m_webSocket.peerAddress();
```

Give me :

[image]

And the rest of the code don't work. I don't know if the address is incorrect, i've tried multiple syntax.

Comment: can you share a link to the example your are playing with?

Comment: Can you connect to echoserver from any other application? In terminal type `telnet localhost 1921` and see if that works. **What is your exact Qt version, OS X version, and where does your Qt binary come from?** If you built Qt yourself, include the contents of `configure.cache` from `qtbase` folder in the build directory.